# How do I share Notepad++ snippets (nppsnippets) with others

Tags: sqlite, notepad++

I have setup a number of custom snippet libraries with the nppsnippets plugin.
I can see where it has the ability to import sqlite files, but I don't see what file(s) to share if I would like to let associates use the libraries I created.

Ideally I would like to share a subset of the libraries I created.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This plugin creates a sqlite database within your %appdata%/Notepad++/plugins/config/ folder named NppSnippets.sqlite.

While Notepad++  is closed, you can overwrite the entire database in your associates appdata folder with the one you have, and the next time Notepad++ is opened, it will have your library in their application.  Alternatively, you can have them use the built-in import tool within notepad++ to import particular libraries from your SQLite database.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you save my time, we should find some usefull snippet archives (to save time) :)